# add Solr to web application using solrj

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, solr, solrj

I want to build a dynamic-web project using Tomcat 9 as my web server. I connect Solr 7 to Java using Solrj and I need to use the web project with Solrj so that I can use Solr in the web project but I am not sure how or if it's applicable.

I try to do this by adding Solrj project to the dynamic-web project but it's not working.

This is my code:

```java
public  String search(String str) throws IOException, SolrServerException {

        SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient
                                .Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/test4")
                                .build();


        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery(str);

        query.setFields("bk");
        query.setStart(0);
        query.setRows(100000);
        str="";
        QueryResponse response = client.query(query);
        SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
        System.out.println(results.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
            {  System.out.println(results.get(i));
            str=str+"\n"+results.get(i);}

      }

        return str;
    }


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      String str="error";
    search("History");
      resp.getWriter().println("testing "+str);

  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so we both can learn. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: Think you , I add the code i tried but i don't think it's useful becuse i am not sure if it's applicable.

Comment: That's a good start posting your script. "its not working": If you have some error code or error log or response code, some strange view from GUI you could/should post that as well. Only the essentials. In case of image use "!" in front of "[some text](image reference)". In the case if no response is seen at all... mention that as such because .. "its not working" is a little broad. ;-) (I'm helping you on making it a valid/good question because I got your q as review; your topic is not my expertise).

Comment: If you check pages like [this](http://www.pathbreak.com/blog/using-solr-from-java-applications-with-solrj) and the help there didn't work out, it will be worth mention it as well in your question. This is effort you showed and is well appreciated and motivates others to help you quicker.

Comment: Also add what you're getting as an output, what actually happens? Iis your `doGet` method invoked at all? maybe this is a framework problem? What framework are you using for your controllers?